# Batch File: Fails to Echo Variable Inside Loop

Tags: for-loop, batch-file

I've hit rock bottom, I can't seem to get this work!

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%g in (1,2,3) do (
set /a c=%%g+32
echo %c%
)

pause
```

But it says ECHO is on, I know this means that it has nothing to display, but how couldn't it have something to display? I tried changing many things (adding/removing setlocal for example) but it won't work.

Any help is GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

```
for %%g in (1,2,3) do (
  set /a c=%%g+32
  echo !c!
)
```

In `set /?` written that we should use `!` for this situation.