# Netstat batch program

Tags: scripting, batch-file

When running this batch script the results are always the same. I believe I am missing something in the syntax. What am I missing?

```
@echo off
netstat -an | find /C "LIST" > tmpFile
set test=<tmpFile
del tmpFile
set max=6
IF !%test! GTR !max! echo Greater than X
IF !%test! LEQ !max! echo Less than X
PAUSE
:EOF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

netstat -an | find /C "LIST" > tmpFile
set /P test=<tmpFile
del tmpFile
set max=20
IF !test! GTR !max! echo Greater than X
IF !test! LEQ !max! echo Less than X
PAUSE
:EOF
```

You need:

1. Remove `%` at variable `test`
2. Add key `/P` in `set` command for variable `test`
3. Add `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`. See also [Batch File: Fails to Echo Variable Inside Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11571926/batch-file-fails-to-echo-variable-inside-loop/11572315#11572315)